# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) while sending post request via ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am writing simple web service to save the data in cache and then retrieve it. When I press the save button, AJAX code runs on server and browser console shows me this error. My C# web service code is:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class stash : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public bool save_value(string new_value)
    {
        //Session["newValue"] = new_value;
        HttpRuntime.Cache["newValue"] = new_value;
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache["newValue"] != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public string get_value()
    {
        object a = HttpRuntime.Cache["newValue"];
        return a.ToString();

    }
}
```

And html page code is ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>
    main page
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#savebtn").click(function () {

            var val = $("#txtsave").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "stash.asmx/save_value",
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset-utf',
                data: JSON.stringify({ new_value: val }),
                dataType: 'bool',
                //cache: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == true) {
                        alert("value has been saved");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("value did not saved");
                    }
                },
            });
        });

        $("#getbtn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "stash.asmx/get_value",
                method: 'GET',
                datatype: 'json',
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#txtget").val(data);
                },
            });
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
Type the value u want to save : <input type="text" id="txtsave" />
    <input type="button" id="savebtn" value="save it" /><br /><br /><br />
    get the value u just saved by pressing this button <input type="button"            id="getbtn" value="get" />
    <input type="text" id="txtget" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct your **contentType: 'application/json;charset-utf'** to **contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'**

Comment: Downvoted for [urgent begging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Comment: same error. no imporvement #MuhammadSaqlain

Comment: A 500 error isn't much to go on.  Can you post the detail + stack trace?  Check Event Viewer for more details.